# Converting string to normal text

Tags: python

I am working in python, and I need to convert an imported string to normal text.  I cannot really use split(), since the text I have is not predictable.

For example, I would have:

```
' "ABC1.2.3.4",
{
    "abc": "4.5.6",
    "cde": 
    [
        {
            "efg": "7.8.9",
            "hij": "1234",
        },
        {
            "efg": "789",
            "hij": "5678",
        }
    ]
} '
```

All I want is the exact same text, just not as a string(remove the ' ') and put it in a list

Comment: `eval()`: `evil` yet `inevitable`

Comment: Are the `'` always the first and last characters?

Comment: @sshashank124: not when there are `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval()`. Not that either would work here as this is *incomplete*.

Comment: Where did you get this string from? What's your desired output as "regular text"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import ast

s = """ "ABC1.2.3.4",
    {
        "abc": "4.5.6",
        "cde": 
        [
            {
                "efg": "7.8.9",
                "hij": "1234",
            },
            {
                "efg": "789",
                "hij": "5678",
            }
        ]
    } """

data = ast.literal_eval("[{}]".format(s))
```

gives

```
['ABC1.2.3.4',
 {'abc': '4.5.6',
  'cde': [{'efg': '7.8.9', 'hij': '1234'}, {'efg': '789', 'hij': '5678'}]}
]
```